# Office 365 Graph API is not able to create non IPM Subtree folder

Tags: email, graph, directory, office365

I am just trying to use the Office 365 Graph API to create some non IPM Subtree mail folder which would be located as the same level as the MsgFolderRoot. And **this kind of folder would be hidden from the end user's outlook**.
However, with the below API post trying to create it under the root folder:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx@xxxx/mailFolders

{
  "displayName": "hiddenfolder",
  "parentFolderId": "root"
}

the folder was created under the "msgfolderroot", but not the "root".

So, is there some guys in the Office 365 Graph API team know this limitation and would there be some plan to provide this ability for the mail folder API?

(explanation about creating non IPM subtree mail fodler under the "root": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659505(v=exchg.150).aspx)

And I am able to create a non IPM subtree folder under the "root" with the EWS managed API.